# Build OpenCV in Visual Studio 2012 with CUDA

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, cuda

I need to compile OpenCV 2.4.5 with Visual Studio 2012. In particular I'm interested in the compilation of gpu module with Cuda 5.0.

To enable CUDA compilation in VS2012 I followed [this guide](http://blog.norture.com/2012/10/gpu-parallel-programming-in-vs2012-with-nvidia-cuda/).

I use CMake to create VS2012 solution, then for each .cu file I change element type from "Custom build rule" to "CUDA C/C++"

I can compile the majority of project files but on some files I've got an annoying problem.

For example fgd_bgfg.cu cause

> error C2039: 'ParameterType': is not a member of
>   'cv::gpu::device::TypeTraits'

But in type_traits.hpp I can read

```
typedef typename type_traits_detail::Select<IsSimpleParameter<UnqualifiedType>::value,
            T, typename type_traits_detail::AddParameterType<T>::type>::type ParameterType;
```

This is a really annoying problem I can't get rid of!

I can't believe no one has already built opencv with VS2012 and GPU, some advice?

Comment: CUDA doesn't officially support VS2012, so it shouldn't be too much of a surprise that building OpenCV with CUDA in VS2012 doesn't work.

Comment: I know it, but many people already work with CUDA with some tricks like the one I linked in the question. Furthermore OpenCV prebuilt library already contains VS2012 binaries. It seems really strange to me that no one have tried to compile GPU module with VS2012.

Comment: I was able to build OpenCV in VS 2012 with latest CUDA 5.5 RC (this version supports VS 2012 officially). There is only one issue : you should set CMake variable CUDA_ATTACH_VS_BUILD_RULE_TO_CUDA_FILE to OFF.

Comment: I'll try it ASAP, which version of OpenCV have you compiled?

Comment: I compiled master branch. But latest OpenCV release (2.4.6) also supports CUDA 5.5, so it should work too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the CUDA compiler can't deal with the template traits technique. A simple way is specifying the TypeTraits template with three primitive types: double, float, int. I'm not sure this way is correct, but the CUDA compiler won't complain.

The code lists here:

```
template<> struct TypeTraits<double>
{
    typedef type_traits_detail::UnConst<double>::type                                                NonConstType;
    typedef type_traits_detail::UnVolatile<double>::type                                             NonVolatileType;
    typedef type_traits_detail::UnVolatile<typename type_traits_detail::UnConst<double>::type>::type UnqualifiedType;
    typedef type_traits_detail::PointerTraits<double>::type                            PointeeType;
    typedef type_traits_detail::ReferenceTraits<double>::type                                        ReferredType;

    enum { isConst          = type_traits_detail::UnConst<double>::value };
    enum { isVolatile       = type_traits_detail::UnVolatile<double>::value };

    enum { isReference      = type_traits_detail::ReferenceTraits<double>::value };
    enum { isPointer        = type_traits_detail::PointerTraits<typename type_traits_detail::ReferenceTraits<double>::type>::value };

    enum { isUnsignedInt    = type_traits_detail::IsUnsignedIntegral<double>::value };
    enum { isSignedInt      = type_traits_detail::IsSignedIntergral<double>::value };
    enum { isIntegral       = type_traits_detail::IsIntegral<double>::value };
    enum { isFloat          = type_traits_detail::IsFloat<double>::value };
    enum { isArith          = isIntegral || isFloat };
    enum { isVec            = type_traits_detail::IsVec<double>::value };

    typedef double ParameterType;
};
template<> struct TypeTraits<float>
{
    typedef type_traits_detail::UnConst<float>::type                                                NonConstType;
    typedef type_traits_detail::UnVolatile<float>::type                                             NonVolatileType;
    typedef type_traits_detail::UnVolatile<typename type_traits_detail::UnConst<float>::type>::type UnqualifiedType;
    typedef type_traits_detail::PointerTraits<float>::type                            PointeeType;
    typedef type_traits_detail::ReferenceTraits<float>::type                                        ReferredType;

    enum { isConst          = type_traits_detail::UnConst<float>::value };
    enum { isVolatile       = type_traits_detail::UnVolatile<float>::value };

    enum { isReference      = type_traits_detail::ReferenceTraits<float>::value };
    enum { isPointer        = type_traits_detail::PointerTraits<typename type_traits_detail::ReferenceTraits<float>::type>::value };

    enum { isUnsignedInt    = type_traits_detail::IsUnsignedIntegral<float>::value };
    enum { isSignedInt      = type_traits_detail::IsSignedIntergral<float>::value };
    enum { isIntegral       = type_traits_detail::IsIntegral<float>::value };
    enum { isFloat          = type_traits_detail::IsFloat<float>::value };
    enum { isArith          = isIntegral || isFloat };
    enum { isVec            = type_traits_detail::IsVec<float>::value };

    typedef float ParameterType;
};

template<> struct TypeTraits<int>
{
    typedef type_traits_detail::UnConst<int>::type                                                NonConstType;
    typedef type_traits_detail::UnVolatile<int>::type                                             NonVolatileType;
    typedef type_traits_detail::UnVolatile<typename type_traits_detail::UnConst<int>::type>::type UnqualifiedType;
    typedef type_traits_detail::PointerTraits<int>::type                            PointeeType;
    typedef type_traits_detail::ReferenceTraits<int>::type                                        ReferredType;

    enum { isConst          = type_traits_detail::UnConst<int>::value };
    enum { isVolatile       = type_traits_detail::UnVolatile<int>::value };

    enum { isReference      = type_traits_detail::ReferenceTraits<int>::value };
    enum { isPointer        = type_traits_detail::PointerTraits<typename type_traits_detail::ReferenceTraits<int>::type>::value };

    enum { isUnsignedInt    = type_traits_detail::IsUnsignedIntegral<int>::value };
    enum { isSignedInt      = type_traits_detail::IsSignedIntergral<int>::value };
    enum { isIntegral       = type_traits_detail::IsIntegral<int>::value };
    enum { isFloat          = type_traits_detail::IsFloat<int>::value };
    enum { isArith          = isIntegral || isFloat };
    enum { isVec            = type_traits_detail::IsVec<int>::value };

    typedef int ParameterType;
};
```

copy the code in type_traits.hpp, behind the original TypeTraits definition. Build...then prey.

Good luck!
:-D

Comment: Using the master branch, I built the Emgu x64 release with VS2012 and CUDA support. To do that, I had to make some changes:
1.modify the Build_Binary_x86.bat to enable CUDA mode
2.Change CUDA's device "Code Generation" compiling parameter: compute_30,sm_30.
By the way, I worked under Windows 7 64.